# Power Supply needs for my first high end gaming Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, power-supply

This is my first time ever asking for help with anything related to computer issues but I feel like this is just too big of a risk for me to just go off of other people's questions. Anyway, this is my first time building a computer in general, so I'm nervous about how much power I need to supply my tower with? Do I run the risk of frying my system? what could happen if I don't supply enough power?

This is my build on www.Pcpartpicker.com 
https://pcpartpicker.com/user/TheAutisticOperator/saved/NNX7WZ

If I'm missing any information let me know. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Sorry to say this site is not a site that will ever engage in an endless thread of what “the best” part/thing is. If you feel unsure about building a machine, then don’t build one and let the pros do it. You will delude yourself into believing you are saving money by building yourself, but honestly you will most likely spend and waste more time and money D.I.Y.ing this than otherwise. Best advice? Don’t build your own system.

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Comment: I'm not asking what to buy so much as how much power yall recommend for this specific build.

Comment: He isn't asking about what specific hardware he should buy but instead how he should go about selecting the right item. It won't become obsolete and others will find it useful.

Comment: 1. Building your own PC is a bit like building your own car from parts you buy retail.  It will costs you a lot more than buying one off-the-shelf, plus you have the responsibility for component selection.  If you aren't an experienced builder with a specific goal and an unusual requirement, and just want the experience and satisfaction, consider a different route.  Get your feet wet by picking up a used computer at a thrift store and fixing it up or enhancing it (even better if you can do that with parts from other junk computers). (cont'd)

Comment: 2. Assuming you started with a build guide at that site, what's the point of using a site like that if you aren't going to trust the recommendations?  3. If your question asked how to figure out the requirements (applicable to any system), it would be on topic.  But asking for a recommendation for a specific configuration won't apply to anything else, so it isn't useful to others (which is kinda the purpose of the site).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

what pcpartpicker says is probably a good guess but add 100w to be safe what you already have is probably good enough is you don't want to upgrade to anything crazy in the future